# How to handle JSON with multiple data

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a simple question. I would like to use JSON file as following:

```
{
"data": {
    "1": {
        "id": 1, 
        "symbol": "A", 
        ...
        },
    }, 
    "1027": {
        "id": 1027, 
        "symbol": "B", 
        ...
        }, 
    },
    ...
}
```

It is from website, and I make a JSON file to parse such as tmp. I wanna see the result of `tmp["data"]["1"]["symbol"]`, and there are 1000 data included. What I said is I would like to check `tmp["data"]["1"]["symbol"]` to `tmp["data"]["1000"]["symbol"]` with for statement. I cannot replace `"1"` part with another index number. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will output all the `symbol` values along with the corresponding `id`s:

```
for data in tmp['data'].values():
    print(data['id'], data['symbol'])
```

Answer (score 1):

For accessing all the sub-elements of `data`, try this -

```
for var in tmp['data'].values():
     print(var['symbol'])
```

This iterates for all the subelements of `data` and prints the `symbol` element in all the subelements.